# svn repository restoration

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I needed to merge some branch repo into another and instead, by mistake, I have used "svn copy" which had overwritten the destination repository and so some of the files were lost. Good news is that I have daily backups created with `svnadmin dump' but I'm not that sure how it's best to proceed in order to restore that lost files and also keep the new ones which have been added later.

I was thinking doing like this:

1. create some svn temporary repository
2. use "svn load /path/to/the/temp-repository/

   cd /path/to/the/temp-repository/

   remove all .svn dirs recursively

   go to the branch that I have overwritten and use rsync to send the lost files to the working repository.

Not sure if this is the best approach. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

**I have better news for you**

Subversion store all history between changes.

When you accidently `svn copy` you added *additional commit* into destination branch. You can

- `svn up GOODREV` to good commit (or `svn co BRANCH@GOODREV` into fresh WC) and commit (minor edit-save-commit) on top of bad
- Undo bad commit by reverse-merge

For svnadmin dump

You have to identify, are these backups incremental (--incremental) or full. In case of full you have to find backup, in which GOODREV exist, `svnadmin load` this dump into **new** repo, `svn copy` from NEW-REPO branch to OLD-REPO branch, kill restored repository

Hint: you have to learn repository administration better: pp. 4-5 is just delirium - SVN repository have absolutely different file-tree and repostory's subtree doesn't exist as physical tree of same structure (and .svn files are Working Copy attribute and storage of WC-metadata)

Bust logical and better (than your) usage of svndump is, again, different. If you still want hide your error from eyes, you have

- Create **new, full dump** for the range of revisions (-r LOWER:UPPER option), which will exclude BADREVISION.
- Disable all connection
- Remove old repository (rm REPODIR + mkdir REPODIR)
- Restore repo from dump

Comment: Hm. I'm still confused. Actually before using `svn copy` I have used `svn del` to remove that branch first and then svn copy from another branch. Could I still restore it?

Comment: How about the files which have been added later to that branch ?